# Can I use inherited class pointers just as parent's?

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointers, constructor

Both of my classes: Parent and Child are the same (for now) and have the same constructor.

```
class Parent{
protected:
  string name;
public:
  Parent(string &n, vector <int> &v) {
  /* read n and v into vars */
};

class Child : public Parent {
public:
  Child(string &n, vector <int> &v) : Parent(n, v) {}
};
vector <int> val;
string nam, numb;
if(val[0] == 0) 
  Child* ptr = new Child(nam, val);
else
  Parent* ptr = new Parent(nam, val);

myMap.insert(Maptype::value_type(numb, ptr) );
```

Is it legal to pass Child* ptr object as Parent* ptr object? I've heard that they have the same pointer type, so it should be alright. Then why am I getting 
warning: unused variable 'ptr'
warning: unused variable 'ptr'
error: 'ptr' was not declared in this scope 
?
My program works fine with Parent class only. I feel like I haven't inherited Parent right.

Comment: "parent/child" is not a good metaphor of the C++ object model and in particular of public inheritance. "Base" and "Derived" are much better. A child *is* not a parent, but derived classes *are* in a sense a version of their public bases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code creates two separate variables called `ptr`, both with very limited scope.

Consider the following:

```
if(val[0] == 0) 
  Child* ptr = new Child(nam, val);
else
  Parent* ptr = new Parent(nam, val);
```

It is equivalent to:

```
if(val[0] == 0) {
  Child* ptr = new Child(nam, val);
} else {
  Parent* ptr = new Parent(nam, val);
}
// neither of the `ptr' variables is in scope here
```

Here is one way to fix your code:

```
Parent* ptr;
if(val[0] == 0) 
  ptr = new Child(nam, val);
else
  ptr = new Parent(nam, val);
```

Once you do this, you also need to make sure that `Parent` has a virtual destructor. See [When to use virtual destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)

Comment: Thank you. It's still kinda mysterious for me why those pointer have the same type.

Comment: @user1078719: Actually, they don't. It is, however, the case that `Child*` can be converted to `Parent*`. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/basics-of-inheritance.html#faq-19.4

Answer (score -1):

because you declare the ptr in the if statement only, try declaring it just above the if statement so it could be like aix answer